# Rails: Get an associations association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

Lets say I have the following associations:

```
class Player
  has_many :team_members
  has_many :teams, through: :team_members, dependent: :destroy

  has_many :invites, class_name: 'Invitation', as: :invitee
end

class Team
  has_many :team_members
  has_many :players, through: :team_members, dependent: :destroy

  has_many :invites, class_name: 'Invitation', as: 'invitee' 
  has_many :invitations, as: :inviter
end

class Invitation
  belongs_to :inviter, polymorphic: true, optional: true
  belongs_to :invitee, polymorphic: true, optional: true
end
```

Essentially both a `Team` and `Player` can be invited to lets say a game and a `Player` creates and owns a team. So when a `Player` logs on I want to show both the invitations that the `Player` received as well as any invitations that any `Team` that the `Player` owns received.

I am looking for something like:

```
player = Player.first
player.invites << player.teams.invites
```

but I can't do the above since `player.teams.invites` returns a type mismatch since it returns `Team` and not `Invitation`

What is an efficient way to return an association and an associations association in the minimum number of queries? I know I can write a loop but am wondering if there is something more elegant.

Comment: Your models, as shown, do not reflect the idea of "owning" a team. It *might* be useful to show your `Invitation` model.

Comment: I added the Invitation model but I was afraid that it might make the question more contrived because a Team can invite a Player to join the Team and a Game can invite a Player or a Team to join a Game, so its a bit of a web. Because a Player can be assigned to more than one Team, any Team a Player is a part of we can think of as "owning" it.

Comment: Are you sure `player.teams.invites` returns `Team`? That seems odd. And, is `invitee` on `Invitation` polymorphic? If not, you have other problems.

Comment: Technically I can't do player.teams.invites. It would throw an error. i would need to loop through each team and do team.invite to get the Invitation. Yes invitee is polymorphic. For any one Invitation, an Inviter can both be a Game or a Team (a Game can invite a Player or a Team to attend a game and a Team can invite a Player to join the team) and the Invitee can be Team or a Player since a Game can invite either :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I think I would do something like:

```
class Invitation
  belongs_to :inviter, polymorphic: true, optional: true
  belongs_to :invitee, polymorphic: true, optional: true

  class << self

    def for_teams(teams)
      where(invitee_type: 'Team', invitee_id: teams) 
    end

  end

end
```

Then, you could do something like:

```
Invitation.for_teams(player.teams)
```

And get back all of the invitations that any team has received where the team has the player as a member.

BTW, I think your `invites` associations are wrong. I believe they should be:

```
class Team
  has_many :team_members
  has_many :players, through: :team_members, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :invites, class_name: 'Invitation', as: :invitee
  has_many :invitations, as: :inviter
end

class Player
  has_many :team_members
  has_many :teams, through: :team_members, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :invites, class_name: 'Invitation', as: :invitee
end
```

As you have it, you're probably going to get incorrect results because you're ignoring the `invitee_type` in your `has_many` calls.

Comment: Thank you for the time and for spotting the incorrect invites association. That probably saved me a few headaches down the line :)